# How to remove "<< Back to List: Accounts" link salesforce from detail page?

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

In the top most left of the any Detail Page, we will have the name of the record (or) the Record auto number.Below that we will have link like this " << Back to List: Apex Classes". How to remove this link?

[image]

How to remove that link shown in image?

Answer (score 2):

This is a standard function and so far you can not remove it.

There is already a discussion about it,

Fix the "Back to List" Link
http://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Bp4f